# R Shiny Flexdashboard sometimes doesn't load locally?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I created my first flexdashboard with runtime: shiny in R on my work computer. I wasn't having issues while I was making it and the final copy was running fine. I have not made any changes since, but now when I run it **sometimes** the dashboard does not load the data in the valueboxes or graphs. To make sure the script was still working, I ran on my personal computer and it rendered as normal.

I am currently trying to get my IT department's help to solve this issue, but none of them know what R is and I do not have enough background knowledge with Shiny to explain what the possible problem could be. My first guess is it's a windows defender firewall issue blocking the local host and ports.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? I've spoken to three different IT support employees and they all feel they don't have enough information to identify the problem. Do you have any advise reagarding questions to ask IT or how to go about solving this issue?

Comment: I had timeout issues when loading large dataset

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've been using the same dataset and it's fairly small, so I don't think that is my issue.

Comment: If you have shiny pro, ask rstudio support

Comment: I don't unfortunately.

Comment: If you suspect it is a firewall issue, have your security team look at firewall traffic logs for the time when someone ran it on a computer and had a problem. They should be able to filter down to just traffic from the computer that ran it. No knowledge of R or Shiny should be required. If the firewall is blocking something, its logs should show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a similar experience when upload a project to server(Shiny Server). You could try the libraries using the project. Because many times they give compatibility problems.